# jquery on handler to fire when setting element value through jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an event handler that fires whenever a user clicks into a box and enters text:

```
$( '#FOO' ).on( 'keyup change paste', function () {
   console.log('this event handler has fired.');    
});
```

I have another piece of code where, instead of allowing the user to type something in themselves, I am setting the value of the element myself:

```
$("#FOO).text('BAR');
```

While this code works, setting the text value of the element named `FOO` to a value of `BAR`, it does not trigger the event handler.  Which `on` event am I missing, apart from `keyup change paste` that I'm already using?

Comment: if it's an `input` element, trigger a `change` event using `trigger()`

Comment: why the downvote for a completely legitimate question?

Comment: the question being "completely legitimate" doesn't make it useful or well researched.

Comment: "Useful" is pretty subjective.  It's a question that I had, which was answered by someone else, making it pretty USEFUL to me.  I tried searching the forum beforehand but didn't see the question that you found.  I researched the question ahead of time by looking for all jquery `on` events, as I thought THAT was the cause of my issue.  Maybe I should have spent that time helping you down off your high horse instead?

Comment: Hey, you asked for feedback, i simply provided. This is a great example of why downvotes don't and will never require comments.

Comment: people like you are a blight on stackoverflow.

Comment: and, yes, useful is subjective. and the purpose of voting on SO is to indicate usefulness and/or quality. both of which *are subjective*. it's perfectly fine for you to disagree. it's expected actually, it being *your* work after all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those events are only registered when the user initiates them. Since you are making the change yourself, you have to simulate the event using `trigger()`.

```js
$( '#FOO' ).on( 'keyup change paste', function () {
   console.log('this event handler has fired.');    
});

$('#FOO').trigger('change').val('triggered');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="FOO"></textarea>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki that's what he does lmao

Comment: all good I countered him.  I actually tested `trigger('change').text('asdf')` as well as `.text('asdf').trigger('change')`, and neither worked for me.  Running `.text('asdf')'` by itself then running `.trigger('change')` on a separate line works though.  Thank you for the help!